# Java Generics and Bounded parameters in subclasses

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to understand how to use generics in the form of a bounded type parameter in an interface. In this case, to avoid casting when using the bounded param in concrete implementations but I'm running into an issue. I will use the following example to illustrate my problem:

There's an interface and two concrete implementations

```
public abstract class Publication {
}


public class Newspaper extends Publication {
}


public class Newspaper extends Publication {
}
```

Then we have an interface representing a publishing house with two concrete implementations, one publishes magazine and the other newspapers

```
public interface Publisher {
    public <T extends Publication >void publish(T publication);
}
```

Here are the two implementations

```
//DOES NOT COMPILE
public class MagazinePublisher implements Publisher{

   @Override
   public void publish(Magazine publication) {
       //do something with the magazine, its already the type we need without casting
   }
}

//COMPILES but a cast is required to get the type I want
public class NewsPaperPublisher implements Publisher{

   @Override
   public  void publish(Publication publication) {
       // Now I need to cast 
       Newspaper newspaper = (Newspaper)publication;
       //Do some stuff here 
   }
}
```

The example maybe a bit contrived... I understand why the MagazinePublisher class doesn't compile: I'm trying to implement the method with a more specific class than defined by the contract of the publish method in the interface. So how do I user generics to avoid the cast in the NewsPaperPublisher class's publish() method?

Comment: Because you have define `T extends Publication` and in your NewsPaperPublisher's publish method you are passing Publication itself rather then passing some class which extends Publication.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to make the interface generic.

```
public interface Publisher <T extends Publication> {
    void publish(T publication);
}
```

Then, instead of `NewspaperPublisher` and `MagazinePublisher`, you can just write `Publisher<Newspaper>` and `Publisher<Magazine>`.

Or if you want to provide different implementations depending on the type, you can write things like

```
public class NewspaperPublisher implements Publisher<Newspaper> {
    @Override
    public void publish(Newspaper publication) {
        // do some stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: this answer is also useful for me , i never use generic interface ever .. :D

Comment: Thank you David, I was trying to do the same thing as the OP and this helped me solve my problem.....